# Is Cameron becoming human?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

I have a question about the season 1 finale of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, **"What He Beheld"**, when Cameron is getting into the vehicle and it blows up because of a bomb and her CHIP was reset and she tries to kill John Conner. So my question is, Cameron was able to scan everything and sense everything because she was a Terminator robot but she could not know or find that there's a bomb attached to her vehicle. Why is this, is she becoming like a human?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminators do not have x ray vision,  and there is no way to detect everything. Terminators are not infallible, they can be tricked into ambushes and explosives. None of this means she's becoming human, in a physical way. It could mean she's acting more human. But her normal terminator skills are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Cameron is a machine and could *theoretically break down the entire car and scan the entire thing*, but that would take a lot of time and there was no reason for her to think there would be a bomb on the car. There was no motive for her to do that. She's a machine, *she doesn't know everything*.

This isn't an indication of her becoming human and it's hard to imagine an argument to suggest that it is.